# Abstract Algebra Computation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Compute:
>
> $3^{47}$ mod $23$
>
> $3^{49}$ mod $7$
>
> $2^{2^{17}}$ mod $23\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ hint: compute first $2^{17} + 1$ mod $19$

This is the first time I've had to compute elements, so I would appreciate any help.

For the first problem, I got $3^{47} \equiv 3^{22} \cdot 3^{22} \cdot 3^{3} \equiv 4$

For the second, I got $3^{49} \equiv (3^7)^7 \equiv 3^7 \equiv 3$

For the third, I'm not really sure where to begin. I don't understand how computing $2^17$ mod $18$ would help. Using Euler's theorem, though, I got that $2^{17}$ mod $18 \equiv 12$ since $\phi(18) = 6$.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I mistyped the third problem. I will ask it in another question.

Comment: First two parts are correct. For the last part, you are calculating $\pmod{19}$ in problem statement and $\pmod{18}$ in your work. Which are you looking for? Also, $2^{17} \pmod{18} \equiv 14$.

Comment: I cannot see the point of computing $2^{17}$ mod $19$. I would recommend computing $2^{17}$ mod $22$.

Comment: @DerekHolt $2^{17} \mod 22$ or $2^{17} \mod 23$?

Comment: @Hawk Definitely $2^{17} \pmod{22}$ since $a^{22} \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Even for the second, $\displaystyle3^3=27\equiv-1\pmod7,$

$\displaystyle\implies3^{49}=(3^3)^{16}\cdot3\equiv(-1)^{16}\cdot3\pmod7 $

For the third,

$\displaystyle2^{\left(2^{17}\right)}\equiv2^{\left(2^{17}\pmod{\phi(23)}\right)}\pmod{23}$

Let us find $\displaystyle2^{17}\pmod{22}$ as $\phi(23)=22$

As $\displaystyle(2^{17},22)=2,$ we shall try finding  $\displaystyle2^{16}\pmod{11}$

As $\displaystyle2^5=32\equiv-1\pmod{11},2^{16}=2\cdot(2^5)^3\equiv2\cdot(-1)^3\pmod{11}\equiv-2\equiv9$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{17}\equiv2\cdot9\pmod{2\cdot11}\equiv18$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{\left(2^{17}\right)}\equiv2^{18}\pmod{23}$

Now, $\displaystyle2^6=64\equiv-5\pmod{23}$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{18}\equiv(-5)^3\equiv-125\equiv13$